# Having trouble with react-grid-layout example

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

Been trying to get into react and was looking at react-grid-layout when I came across a bit of a roadblock. I've pasted in the example from [here](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx) essentially as is, but for some reason, when I drag an element it's not sticking.  The error I'm getting in the console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onLayoutChange is not a function
```

I'm sure it's a simple thing that I'm missing, but this is my first React project and I would appreciate some guidance.

My code is included below:

```
    'use strict';
    var React = require('react');
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var ResponsiveReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout').Responsive;

    /**
     * This layout demonstrates how to use a grid with a dynamic number of     elements.
     */
    var AddRemoveLayout = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps() {
      return {
        className: "layout",
        cols: {lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2},
        rowHeight: 100
      };
    },

    getInitialState() {
      return {
        items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(i, key, list) {
          return {i: i, x: i * 2, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2, add: i === list.length -    1};
       }),
      newCounter: 0
      };
    },

    createElement(el) {
      var removeStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '2px',
        top: 0,
        cursor: 'pointer'
      };
      var i = el.add ? '+' : el.i;
      return (
        <div key={i} _grid={el}>
          {el.add ?
            <span className="add text" onClick={this.onAddItem} title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
          : <span className="text">{i}</span>}
        <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}>x</span>
      </div>
    );
    },

    onAddItem() {
      console.log('adding', 'n' + this.state.newCounter);
      this.setState({
      // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
      items: this.state.items.concat({
        i: 'n' + this.state.newCounter,
        x: this.state.items.length * 2 % (this.state.cols || 12),
        y: Infinity, // puts it at the bottom
        w: 2,
        h: 2
      }),
      // Increment the counter to ensure key is always unique.
      newCounter: this.state.newCounter + 1
    });
  },

  // We're using the cols coming back from this to calculate where to add new items.
  onBreakpointChange(breakpoint, cols) {
    this.setState({
      breakpoint: breakpoint,
      cols: cols
    });
  },

  onLayoutChange(layout) {
    this.props.onLayoutChange(layout);
    this.setState({layout: layout});
  },

  onRemoveItem(i) {
    console.log('removing', i);
    this.setState({items: _.reject(this.state.items, {i: i})});
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Item</button>
        <ResponsiveReactGridLayout onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange} onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
            {...this.props}>
          {_.map(this.state.items, this.createElement)}
        </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = AddRemoveLayout;


React.render(<AddRemoveLayout/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Could you specify which version or React you are using? If you are using v0.14 that could be a problem since they are still working on support for it.

Comment: Using 

    "version": "0.13.3",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are receiving is an error about a missing prop. In a react component you basically have 2 places to keep your data, in its parent and in your component itself. Your parent often has props while declaring it because those are properties you pass to the child (like an attribute in an HTML tag). Then we have the state which is data inside a component itself.

The error you are receiving is saying that we didn't get a required prop from our parent *(You can also see that inside the onLayoutChange(layout) function a call is being made to the this.props.onLayoutChange(layout) method)*.

So basically we are missing a few props. In the example from GitHub there is a root file called test-hook.jsx (https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/test-hook.jsx). This root node has as a child ( the code you are trying to render directly ) in which it is passing the required function as a property.

You can either use the test-hook.jsx or you can write your own root node which has a state with the layout and the required function which updates that state (see the github example on how to do that).

Comment: That being said, he can just remove the `this.props.onLayoutChange(layout);` call.

Answer (score 1):

So after some searching, I figured out that the example was specifying the onLayoutChange function as a placeholder.  If I wanted a custom funcion, I needed to define that.

Simply removing this function altogether and using the default fixed the issue.

Remove this:

```
onLayoutChange(layout) {
  this.props.onLayoutChange(layout);
  this.setState({layout: layout});
},
```

Comment: What default? You'd better just delete the `this.props.onLayoutChange(layout);` but leave the `this.setState({layout: layout});`. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Dirk-Jan explained it well. But the proper solution IMHO is to remove the prop call:

```
onLayoutChange(layout) {
  // this.props.onLayoutChange(layout);
  this.setState({layout: layout});
},
```

So the meaningful part is still there. In the examples the test-hook.jsx parent has to get hold of the layout so it can display it outside of the layout container for demonstration purposes. In a real-world application we don't need that.